# Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::onlyTrashed does not exist

Tags: laravel, eloquent, soft-delete

When I try to use soft delete on one of app's model I get **Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::onlyTrashed does not exist** exception. On user model it is working. They both use SoftDeletes trait.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to call parent::boot() in the model's boot method. I think the same problem can occur with model's constructor.

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot(); //this was missing

    self::creating(function($model) {
        $event = self::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
        $model->identifier = $event ? ($event->identifier+1) : 1000;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an empty constructor method in my model which caused this issue. When I removed this constructor, it worked normally. It also worked normally when I put parent::boot in the constructor,